# Editing a pandas dataframe, and I simply don't know why

Tags: python, pandas

I'm perplexed whereby I cannot seem to update a row in pandas. I have tried a) creating a copy (and deep copy), since I only need to change the copy.

```
df_company = df.copy(deep=True)
df_company = df_company[df_company["Market"]==company_name]
df_company = df_company[( df_company["Date"] < pd.to_datetime(date_start, dayfirst=True))]
df_company.iloc[j]["Quantity"] += int(remainder_shares)
```

The last row never updates. This is the error generated:

```
<ipython-input-10-9d795087e048>:56: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

`j` is used because there is a loop: `for j in range(0, i)` so how can I access that row by index and then column and then update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `Quantity` with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df_company.iloc[j, df_company.columns.get_loc("Quantity")] += int(remainder_shares)
```